# If you work hard enough next month

Tags: grammar

Does B's sentence in bold sound natural to native speakers of English?

A: I really want that sports car.

B: Well, December is not only the last month of the year but also the competition month for sales representatives of our company. The higher the amounts you achieve, the higher the bonus you get. **If you work hard enough next month, you can buy the car you want next year.**

Comment: Yes, that sounds fine.

Comment: "**The higher the amounts you achieve**" is grammatical but sounds peculiar, "**The more sales you make**" is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds fine if the month it was spoken in was November i.e. 'next month' being December.

Comment: Yes, the conversation occurs in November. By the way, are you a native speaker of English?

Comment: The definition of a native speaker is person of any nationality living in an English-speaking country on a daily basis and speak English at the same level of proficiency as their mother tongue. So, yes, I am a native speaker of English. Thanks! :)

Comment: Which country are you from?